# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'... using android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, material-design

I am using this library https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

when I try run my project I get the following error:

**Error:**

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
>   finished with non-zero exit value 2

**If I try use jdk1.7**

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 2

**Here is my build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

productFlavors {
}


packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs/httpclient', include: ['*.jar'])

compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.6.0'    
compile 'com.blunderer:materialdesignlibrary:2.0.0'     
compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'    


//https://github.com/mikepenz
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:3.1.2@aar') {
    transitive = true
} 
compile('com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:5.0.7@aar') {
    transitive = true
}


compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.4.0@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
}
```

I also tries these solutions, but it does not work:

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
```

and

```
dependencies {

...
    compile 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.2'   
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue should be fixed by specifying -

```
defaultConfig {        
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

You can read more about it at [65K Method Limit](https://developer.android.com/intl/ko/tools/building/multidex.html)